# Export data to excel in loop

Tags: oracle, download, phpexcel, export-to-excel

```
`$query = "SELECT DISTINCT TITLE, PID, TYPE, SUM(DAYCOUNT) AS tot, ROUND(SUM(DAYCOUNT)/( SELECT SUM(DAYCOUNT) FROM REPORT_LIST_VIEW), 4) AS per FROM REPORT_LIST_VIEW WHERE DAYCOUNT > '0' GROUP BY TITLE, PID, TYPE ORDER BY tot DESC";
        //print $query; exit;
        $res = db_query($query);
            while ( $dataFetched = $res->fetchAssoc() ) {
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', $dataFetched['title'])
            ->setCellValue('B1', $dataFetched['tot'])
            ->setCellValue('C1', $dataFetched['per']);

}`
```

I am trying to export my oracle query results to an xls file with `PHPExcel.php` library. Xls file is generating and downloading to web folder (where the download script file is saved). But the xls file only contains the last query result.

Questions

1. How can i run a loop to store all results to xls file each row.
2. How can i download xls file to my local system instead of web hosted folder. Normal download with a prompt pop asking for saving.
3. How can i define a custom file name like `report.xls` to the downloading file.

**Working code (xls file is downloading to web root)**

```
`/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', TRUE);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', TRUE);
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
define('EOL',(PHP_SAPI == 'cli') ? PHP_EOL : '<br />');
/** Include PHPExcel */
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/../Classes/PHPExcel.php';
// Create new PHPExcel object
echo date('H:i:s') , " Create new PHPExcel object" , EOL;
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set document properties
echo date('H:i:s') , " Set document properties" , EOL;
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
                             ->setTitle("PHPExcel Test Document")
                             ->setSubject("PHPExcel Test Document")
                             ->setDescription("Test document for PHPExcel, generated using PHP classes.")
                             ->setKeywords("office PHPExcel php")
                             ->setCategory("Test result file");
echo date('H:i:s') , " Add some data" , EOL;
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT TITLE, PID, TYPE, SUM(DAYCOUNT) AS tot, ROUND(SUM(DAYCOUNT)/( SELECT SUM(DAYCOUNT) FROM REPORT_LIST_VIEW), 4) AS per FROM REPORT_LIST_VIEW WHERE DAYCOUNT > '0' GROUP BY TITLE, PID, TYPE ORDER BY tot DESC";
//print $query; exit;
$res = db_query($query);
$rowNumber = 1;
while ( $dataFetched = $res->fetchAssoc() ) {
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A'.$rowNumber, $dataFetched['title'])
        ->setCellValue('B'.$rowNumber, $dataFetched['tot'])
        ->setCellValue('C'.$rowNumber, $dataFetched['per']);
    $rowNumber++;
}
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(8)->setRowHeight(-1);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A8')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
// Rename worksheet
echo date('H:i:s') , " Rename worksheet" , EOL;
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');
// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
// Save Excel 2007 file
echo date('H:i:s') , " Write to Excel2007 format" , EOL;
$callStartTime = microtime(true);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', __FILE__));
$callEndTime = microtime(true);
$callTime = $callEndTime - $callStartTime;
echo date('H:i:s') , " File written to " , str_replace('.php', '.xlsx', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME)) , EOL;
echo 'Call time to write Workbook was ' , sprintf('%.4f',$callTime) , " seconds" , EOL;
// Echo memory usage
echo date('H:i:s') , ' Current memory usage: ' , (memory_get_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) , " MB" , EOL;
// Save Excel 95 file
echo date('H:i:s') , " Write to Excel5 format" , EOL;
$callStartTime = microtime(true);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xls', __FILE__));
$callEndTime = microtime(true);
$callTime = $callEndTime - $callStartTime;

echo date('H:i:s') , " File written to " , str_replace('.php', '.xls', pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_BASENAME)) , EOL;
echo 'Call time to write Workbook was ' , sprintf('%.4f',$callTime) , " seconds" , EOL;
// Echo memory usage
echo date('H:i:s') , ' Current memory usage: ' , (memory_get_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) , " MB" , EOL;
// Echo memory peak usage
echo date('H:i:s') , " Peak memory usage: " , (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) , " MB" , EOL;

// Echo done
echo date('H:i:s') , " Done writing files" , EOL;
echo 'Files have been created in ' , getcwd() , EOL;`
```

**Updated code.(Added to download xls file to local)**

`// Add some data
    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT TITLE, PID, TYPE, SUM(DAYCOUNT) AS tot, ROUND(SUM(DAYCOUNT)/( SELECT SUM(DAYCOUNT) FROM REPORT_LIST_VIEW), 4) AS per FROM REPORT_LIST_VIEW WHERE DAYCOUNT > '0' GROUP BY TITLE, PID, TYPE ORDER BY tot DESC";
    //print $query; exit;
    $res = db_query($query);
    $rowNumber = 1;
    while ( $dataFetched = $res->fetchAssoc() ) {
        $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A'.$rowNumber, $dataFetched['title'])
            ->setCellValue('B'.$rowNumber, $dataFetched['tot'])
            ->setCellValue('C'.$rowNumber, $dataFetched['per']);
        $rowNumber++;
    }
    // Miscellaneous glyphs, UTF-8
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension(8)->setRowHeight(-1);
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A8')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);
    // Rename worksheet
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Page & Files Reports ');
    // Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="page_file_report.xls"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');
    // If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
    header ('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
    header ('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT'); // always modified
    header ('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
    header ('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.0
    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
    $objWriter->save('php://output');
    exit;`

Comment: I removed all printing of error reporting from page. Still its adding html content instead of results.

Answer (score 0):

**Question #1:**

Keep a row counter, and modify the cell address with the new row number for each loop:

```
$query = "SELECT DISTINCT TITLE, PID, TYPE, SUM(DAYCOUNT) AS tot, ROUND(SUM(DAYCOUNT)/( SELECT SUM(DAYCOUNT) FROM REPORT_LIST_VIEW), 4) AS per FROM REPORT_LIST_VIEW WHERE DAYCOUNT > '0' GROUP BY TITLE, PID, TYPE ORDER BY tot DESC";
//print $query; exit;
$res = db_query($query);
$rowNumber = 1;
while ( $dataFetched = $res->fetchAssoc() ) {
    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A'.$rowNumber, $dataFetched['title'])
        ->setCellValue('B'.$rowNumber, $dataFetched['tot'])
        ->setCellValue('C'.$rowNumber, $dataFetched['per']);
    $rowNumber++;
}
```

**Question #2:**

Take a look at the download examples like `01simple-download-xls.php` in the `Examples` folder of PHPExcel..... reading the documentation and looking at the examples should answer 99% of your possible questions

**Question #3:**

You can't absolutely, that's up to the person who is downloading the file; the best you can do is use the `Content-Disposition` in the response headers (see answer to Question #2) to "suggest" a filename for the download

Comment: Thanks Mark. Your code worked as expected. I tried the code in `01simple-download-xls.php` to download file. But the downloaded file contains the HTML of the file instead of results. I am posting my updated code in the question.

Comment: Then don't have any html being generated if the request is for the export.... don't echo/print anything to the browser for the export

Comment: If you're not sending anything to the browser, are you sure that the code is being called? And check your logs

Comment: Yes..My code is calling but the downloaded xls file `page_file_report.xlx` contains menu links text, search form label etc instead of SQL results.

Comment: Then you need to suppress that HTML from being generated when you've requested the Excel file. If you're running through a framework, it may well be sending markup, and overriding the headers that you're setting here